# Contraction function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

We wanna show that the sequence $(t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ recursively defined by $t_1=1$, $t_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+t_n}$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to $-1+\sqrt 2$.

NOTE: i have to use the  CONTRACTION THEOREM TO SHOW THIS. I have to make the recursively sequence a $f(x)$ and SHOW  that it is a contraction.

Now i started on this problem and i used according to the Contraction Theorem that

For every $x\subset$ $I$ where $I=[0,1]$ we have that $f(x)\subset I$

And that there is a number $c$ such that $0\leq c<1$ such that for every $x,y$ in the interval we have $|f(x) - f(y)|\leq c|x-y|$

Now i started of and then after some algebra i got $\leq \frac{|x-y|}{|2+x| |2+y|}$

but now should i take $x=0, y=0$ because that is the minimim of the interval and i will get $c=\frac{1}{4}$? But am left with the fraction $\frac{1}{4} |x-y|$ which is also true according to the definition but i dont understand that why $|x-y|$ in the numerator still can stand after we decided that in the denominator we plugged in $x=0, y=0$

Comment: We don't need to actually put $x=y=0$, rather think it this way that $\frac{|x-y|}{|2+x|.|2+y|}\le \frac{|x-y|}4$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha but how do you know you can choose a 4???

Comment: By finding the maximum of $|2+x|.|2+y|$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha why should we focus on the denominator and why should we try to find the max? Also i dont understand the full use of this theorem, why is it needed for what purpose??

Comment: Sorry, i meant the minimum of the denominator. Because by finding the minimum of the denominator we can find a constant $c$, such that $1/c$ can serve as the contraction factor

Comment: @AbishankaSaha but why is 0 the minimum? And should we always plug in the minimum value on the interval?

Comment: Because the function $|2+x|.|2+y|$ is increasing on the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha ok but still i dont get the use of the contraction theorem as a whole. And you are saying that we should not plug in a zero? But if the minimum of the interval [2,infinity] then what would have been the minimum a 4? Should we plug in the numbers x=y=2? In this case

Comment: `We wanna show that the sequence ... recursively defined by ...` The sentence is unfinished. You want to show that the sequence *does what*?

Comment: @dxiv is also a contraction with contraction constant $c$

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by the recursive sequence being a contraction function?

Comment: @dxiv yes i changed the question now

Comment: @dxiv also note that i dont fully understand the use of the contraction theorem i dont know what is does exactly

Comment: For the relationship to contractions, see [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2578999/291201). But you don't *have* to use contractions in order to prove the convergence of *this* sequence, so you'll have to decide on which question you mean to ask.

Comment: If $t$ is the limit then $t=1/(2+t)$, so $t(2+t)=1$, and $t^2+2t-1=0$ with solutions $t=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt8}2=-1\pm\sqrt2$, rule out the negative $-1-\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Mirko yes but i want to show it according to $f(x)$ a contraction

Comment: @dxiv  i dont get the relation $|f(x)-f(y)|<=c|x-y|$ how can that relation show that $f(x)$ will be a contraction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) instead to find $0\leq c<1$, i.e. $\exists \varepsilon \in (x,y) \subset [0,1]$ such that 
$$\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|=\left|f'(\varepsilon)\right|\cdot\left|y-x\right|$$
where $f(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$. Or
$$\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{(2+\varepsilon)^2}\right|\cdot\left|y-x\right|=\frac{1}{(2+\varepsilon)^2}\cdot\left|y-x\right| \tag{1}$$
and since $0\leq \varepsilon \leq 1 \Rightarrow 2\leq 2+\varepsilon \leq 3 \Rightarrow 4\leq (2+\varepsilon)^2 \leq 9 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4}\geq \frac{1}{(2+\varepsilon)^2} \geq \frac{1}{9}$. As a result, $(1)$ becomes
$$\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|\leq\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left|y-x\right| \tag{2}$$
for $\forall x,y \in [0,1]$. So we take $c=\frac{1}{4}$.

---

Now, let's show that $$\forall x \in [0,1] \Rightarrow f(x) \in [0,1] \tag{3}$$

$0\leq x \leq1 \Rightarrow 2\leq 2+x \leq3 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\geq \frac{1}{2+x} \geq \frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow 1 > \frac{1}{2} \geq f(x) \geq \frac{1}{3}>0$.

---

From $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have that $f(x)$ a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) on $[0,1]$. According to [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) and the fact that $t_1=1 \in [0,1]$, there $\exists! t^{*} \in [0,1]$ such that $t^{*}=f(t^{*})$ where $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n=t^{*}$ or
$$t^{*}=\frac{1}{2+t^{*}} \Leftrightarrow (t^{*})^2+2t^{*}-1=0$$
This has 2 solutions $-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $-1-\sqrt{2}$, but only $-1+\sqrt{2} \in [0,1]$

Comment: Why did you take $|f’(x)|$ as c??  Why take the derivative ?? Is the constant $c$ a derivative of f(x)??? And also where did i proved that $f(x)$ lies in the interval [0,1]?

Comment: I didn't take $|f'(x)|$ as $c$. I used MVT to maximise $|f'(x)|$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: ok but it seems you replaced $c$ with the derivative of $f(x)$?and then you maximized the derivative and took that as a c? I really have to use the contraction theorem not the mvt :-(

Comment: I really have to understand what $|f(x)-f(y)|<=c|x-y|$ means what does that mean?? How can i sketch that?

Comment: Yes, I used max of $|f'(x)|$ on $[0,1]$ as $c$, which fits the purposes. I used MVT to show that there exists such a $c=\frac{1}{4}$ which makes $f(x)$ a contraction mapping. Now, you can use Banach fixed point theorem, more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225451/contraction-mapping-in-the-context-of-fx-n-x-n1/2225503#2225503)

Comment: You also stated "For every $x\subset I$ where $I=[0,1]$ we have that $f(x)\subset I$" ... I assume you proved it.

Comment: no i did not proved that yet. How cAn i prove that? Thanks for the info still somehow not so clear but a bit more now

Comment: @Mark I have updated my answer with a lot more details, including extra proofs, let me know if more clarity is still required. Specifically, I believe that by "CONTRACTION THEOREM" you mean "Banach fixed-point theorem" which is a really famous and popular result.

Comment: where were you all the time men!! You really nailed it !!! But i have one more question left what does the statement $|f(x)-f(y)|<=c|x-y|$ really means can you explain it in your own words then i would understand it fully

Comment: In the context of contraction mapping and this particular example, it means that "for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ there exists a constant $c$, $0\leq c < 1$, such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq c|x-y|$". It is important to remember **"for all $x,y$"** part.

Comment: alright thank you alot!!! Its clear to me now!!!